# All my outlets are 220-240v , one shows 130-140v. What could the problem be?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, socket

[image: Main breaker panel]I recently wanted to use an outlet that I had rewired 5-6 years ago (along with the whole house) and all my other outlets are 220-240v, but this one shows 130-140v.
What could the problem be? I intend to plug in a spare Fridge to it and would love it if I don't have to hack away at the walls to run new wiring. I am not a professional but I recall someone saying that electricity running to my house is on a "3-phase system" Not sure if that means anything or helps

*edit The location is Warsaw, Poland. 90% of the wiring and fuse boxes etc was ripped out and new/modern installed 5-6 years ago, this socket MIGHT have escaped someone's attention and only gotten a new plastic "facade" but not wires.
Not sure if that means anything or helps

Thanks in advance.

Josef

*pics below

[image: The sockwet in question]

[[image: The Nearest breaker panel][2]]

[image: Close-up of main breaker panel (pic3)]

*edit 3
closeup, the brown lump was just tape, covering some shoddy cutting work. Could this cause the loss of 90-100v? [image: brown lump was just tape]

Comment: Mentioning where in the world you are would probably help (not your street address, but country is usually handy for this sort of question, as supplies and common practices vary between countries and regions.)

Comment: Thank you Ecnerwal :) Good point.

Comment: If you can upload a picture of the breaker panel, that may help. Identify the particular breaker for this outlet, if you know which one it is.

Comment: Will do, pics uploading now . Thank you.

Comment: Is this an incomplete job? What's with all the exposed wires near the main panel?

Comment: Job is complete, the wires are not so much exposed as simply not plastered over for aesthetic reasons. They're "exposed", but fully secure, incase I want to add more in the future, and then I won't have to break the plaster, etc. Altho the wife has been nagging me about it (among 999 other things that matter next to nothing) :) .  Since it's in the utility room which doubles as my workshop, it doesn't bother me.

Comment: The insulation of the blue wire on the outlet you're looking at is damaged, which is unsafe.  What's the brown lump on the wire a bit farther back?  It looks like about 2x the thickness of the wire.  If that's a badly done splice, resistance over it could be causing a substantial voltage drop as well as generating enough heat to be a fire hazard.

Comment: unless the second damage point removed a large chunk of the copper it shouldn't have any impact on the output voltage.  (If the wire was almost cut through it could cause a large voltage drop and severe heating problem, but that doesn't appear to be the case.)  While not appearing to be the cause of your problem, the end of that wire needs to be removed at the point of insulation damage, and if too short a pigtail attached.  Use whatever the approved means to join to wires is where you live; the US normally uses wire nuts, I believe the UK screw terminals, but have no idea about Polish code.